# Use vlookup for unspecified amount of columns

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

hi have this code to use vlookup for the roughhly 600 columns, the code works when i used

```
wslookup.range("D2:D600").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C2,'PM FLEET'!$A$1:$D$603,4,FALSE)
```

but doesnt work when i try to use xldown - I am constantly getting the

> error 1004

Are there any other methods i can use to use vlookup until the last entry Thanks is advance!

```
Set wslookup = Workbooks("bdncasemacro.xlsm").Worksheets("Working")
wslookup.Range(Range("D2"), Range("D2").End(xlDown)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C2,'PM FLEET'!$A$1:$D$603,4,FALSE)"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your column D in sheet "Working" is blank, you will be filling the formula up to final row which is row 1,048,576. Suggest you capture the final required row from sheet "PM fleet" i.e. finalrow = Workbooks("bdncasemacro.xlsm").Sheets("PM FLEET").Range("D2").End(xlDown).Row

And use finalrow as the end range in your "Working" sheet

Comment: hi i final outcome i want is for the vlookup formula to be applied to all the occupied cell in column D, as i might add data and do not want a fixed range

Comment: Can I know what do you have in column D sheet "Working" currently? .End(xlDown) is equivalent to ctrl+down arrow. So if it is blank, it will go to the final row in an excel spreadsheet. if there are blanks in between, it will get stuck when it hits the 1st blank. If it is the latter, you can try Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: hi yes there a blanks in between, how do i implement the Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row into my code, sorry im quite new at this.

Comment: Sure on this part: wslookup.Range(Range("D2"), Range("D2").End(xlDown)).Formula, change it to: wslookup.Range(Range("D2"), Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)).Formula

Comment: that's weird, works fine for me. Can I get your full code that failed? It should like so: Set wslookup = Workbooks("bdncasemacro.xlsm").Worksheets("Working")
wslookup.Range(Range("D2"), Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C2,'PM FLEET'!$A$1:$D$603,4,FALSE)" and Column D where this macro populates, should not be blank

Comment: i think it is the cause of my data, column D is a mixture of blanks and data

Comment: It doesn't matter if blanks, as the Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp) will actually state the final populated row of the column. Perhaps you can walk me through in depth of your data structure

Comment: There is around 600 rows , and column D have some that is blank, after going through the vlookup, it should either become N/A or AC

Comment: Can you type out the exact code as well? My script works fine with blanks in between up to 1000 rows

Answer (score 0):

You not specify from where your `Range("D2")`

```
With wslookup
    .Range(.Range("D2"), .Range("D2").End(xlDown)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C2,'PM FLEET'!$A$1:$D$603,4,FALSE)"
End With
```